# EF Core (Code First): Can not save model to database -> SqlException Invalid Column Name

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I'm working with EF Core (code-first and migrations).

When I try simple to save my model(offer) to the database with:

```
_context.Offers.Add(offer);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I get an exception from Entity Framework:

> SqlException: Invalid Column Name 'UserGroupId'

But there is **NO** such `UserGroupId` property on my `Offer` class. I removed it from the `Offer` model class.

And also there is **NO** `UserGroupId` column within the database table.

When I checked my logs, I saw that Entity Framework generates a SQL INSERT statement with this `UserGroupId` column.

**Question:**

Does anybody have an idea where Entity Framework has any references to this `UserGroupId` ghost column?

Thank you for any feedback or tip.

Oliver

**UPDATE 1**:

Now it gets really strange after I did the radical step.

1. I deleted the whole database
2. I deleted also the whole Migrations-Folder
3. I compiled the whole solution (successfully)
4. Then I added a new migration with following command: `add migration initDb
5. Then I created the database with: `update-database

And finally I checked the generated `Offers` table again.

And what I see is, that the `UserGroupId` column is still generated again in this table...

Is there some magic in EF, which I have to know? Why is EF still generating this `UserGroupId` column?

**Update 2**

Here is my Offer model. I think it's really simple and I see no
reason, why the UserGroupId is generated into the table.
The UserGroupId was a wrong property in the Offer model class.
I removed it.

```
namespace Common.Models
{
    public class Offer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }

        public DateTime ValidTo { get; set; }
        public bool PickupLocationVerified { get; set; }
        public string PickupStreet { get; set; }
        public string PickupPlace { get; set; }
        public string PickupZip { get; set; }
        public Country PickupCountry { get; set; }
        public string Longitude { get; set; }
        public string Latitude { get; set; }
        public Order Order { get; set; }
        public User Supplier { get; set; }

        public int SupplierId { get; set; }
        public SupplierRating SupplierRating { get; set; }

        public int? SupplierRatingId { get; set; }
        public ConsumerRating ConsumerRating { get; set; }

        public int? ConsumerRatingId { get; set; }

        public List<Message> Messages { get; set; }
        public List<Image> Images { get; set; }
        public List<Article> Articles { get; set; }

        public bool Active { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public DateTime UpdateDate { get; set; }

        public Group Group { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your Offers model

Comment: I think thats this prop "public Group Group { get; set; }" creates UserGroupId in db, just remove it and try again add migration

Comment: Hi @itikhomi , thanks for your answer and effort to help me. I found the answer as you can read below. It was a long night and I didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.
The Problem was in the UserGroup model class.

There was still a wrong property:

```
public List<Offer> Offers { get; set; }
```

I honestly can not believe, that I didn't see it before.

Thanks and sorry to everyone.